# Midnight Commander и выбор редактора файлов при создании файла

Tags: linux

При первом создании файла (Shift+F4) с Midnight Commander выбросило в терминал, где выводился список редакторв на выбор, выбрать редактор так и не удалось... Стандарный редактор работает, но если отключить его в конфиге то по нажатию (Shift+F4) выбрасывает в терминал, где ничего не выводится и что не нажимаешь ничего не происходит, а просто пишутся символы в терминал. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваш `.bashrc` добавьте

```
export EDITOR="vim"
```

Comment: Это вернет выбор редактор или установинт определенный?

Comment: Этой строкой вы определите редактор по умолчанию, он будет вызываться при нажатии F4, когда снята галка "Встроенный редактор". В данном случае это будет vim.пс а какая у вас система? Спрашиваю, потому что ни разу не видел, что-бы предлагался выбор редакторов

Comment: ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Почему-то не могу комментировать ответ, который дал @Semyon, поэтому пишу тут. @Semyon, если вы имеете в виду стандартный MC'шный, то меня в нем не устраивает то, что он не vim - банально не дотягивает он по необходимому/привычному мне функционалу.